# Elastic search structure AND/EXISTS

Tags: elasticsearch

Im new to Elasticsearch and this is driving me crazy. The docs are pretty unhelpful and so about 6 hours in I come to the amazing SO community.

I have a query which is implemented all over a large and 95% finished website, so I cannot rewrite much at this point.

I need add a check to make sure that the userID is not null. In SQL this would take seconds, but I have a pretty large query which is giving me either crazy unhelpful error messages or not working. I have tried restructuring, moving the "exists" into an existing "and" where it doesnt work at all.

This is what I have:

```
GET _search
{
"from": 0,
"size": 30,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        }, 
        "filter": {
            "and": [
            {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                   {
                        "exists" : { "field" : "userID" }
                   }
                ]
            }
            },{
                "term": {
                    "property.rental": false
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "property.status": 100
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "property.showOnHomepage": true
                }
            } 
         ]
       }
    }
},
"sort": {
    "_script": {
        "script": "Math.random()",
        "type": "number",
        "params": {},
        "order": "asc"
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "min_price": {
        "min": {
            "field": "basePrice"
        }
    },
    "max_price": {
        "max": {
            "field": "basePrice"
        }
    },
    "avg_price": {
        "avg": {
            "field": "basePrice"
        }
    }
},
"filter": {
    "range": {
        "property.price": {
            "lte": 1000000000
        }
    }
}
}
```

This gives the following results:

```
{
"took": 7,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 0,
  "max_score": null,
  "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
  "min_price": {
     "value": null
  },
  "max_price": {
     "value": null
  },
  "avg_price": {
     "value": null
  }
}
}
```

I simply don't understand where to place the

```
 "exists" : { "field" : "userID" }
```

inorder for it to filter out just the properties with null for a userID.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Post some sample docs (preferably with a curl recreation). For instance, are you sure your value is empty or null or could it be the string "null". At first glance, your query looks right to me.

Comment: I would advise starting with a much simpler query to make certain your exists filter is doing what you want. Once you have that working you can slowly add additional filters, sorting and aggregations, but right now all of that will just get in the way. Start with just a match_all query and the exists filter and check to see that it's working.